Why is my BIOS Disk Read program halting instead of printing?
I've started a project on writing an OS recently, and it was going well until "disk reading".
The code should load the next sector and print the letter "H" which is stored just outside the bootloader in the byte right after the 55AA bit signature just outside what the BIOS loads by default.
org 0x7C00
bits 16

; Variables for CHS conversion
tmp: db 0
sct: db 0
hed: db 0
cyl: db 0
spt: db 0
hct: db 0
bdv: db 0
snm: db 0

mov [bdv], dl

jmp main


; lbaRead
; Reads sectors using LBA
; bx: LBA Address
; ax: Number of sectors
; dl: Drive number
lbaRead:
    ; Read the Disk Geometry
    mov ah, 8
    int 0x13
    inc dh
    mov [hct], dh
    and cl, 0x3F
    mov [spt], cl
    ; Error Handling
    jc err

    ; Convert LBA to CHS
    ; Store Sector to read number (snm)
    mov [snm], ax
    ; Calculate temporary value (tmp) and sector
    mov ax, bx
    mov bx, [spt]
    div bx
    mov [tmp], al
    inc ah
    mov [sct], ah
    ; Calculate Head and Cylinder
    mov ax, [tmp]
    mov bx, [hct]
    div bx
    mov [hed], ah
    mov [cyl], al

    ; Read the disk
    mov ah, 0x02
    mov al, [snm]
    mov ch, [cyl]
    mov cl, [sct]
    mov dh, [hed]
    mov bx, 0x7E00
    int 0x13
    ; Error handling
    jc err
    
main:
    mov bx, 1
    mov ax, 1
    call lbaRead
    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov al, [0x7E00]
    int 0x10
    jmp $

err:
    mov ah, 0x0B
    mov bl, 0x4
    int 0x10
    jmp $

; Pad to 512 bytes and add 0x55AA cap
times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55, 0xaa

The code SHOULD print a solitary "H", which is the first byte in the next sector.


However, instead of printing anything it just halts.
EDIT: So far, I've made a few changes to hopefully fix things. It hasn't though...
org 0x7C00
bits 16

mov ax, 0
mov es, ax
mov ds, ax

; Variables for CHS conversion
tmp: db 0
sct: db 0
hed: db 0
cyl: db 0
spt: db 0
hct: db 0
bdv: db 0
snm: db 0

mov [bdv], dl

jmp main


; lbaRead
; Reads sectors using LBA
; bx: LBA Address
; ax: Number of sectors
; dl: Drive number
lbaRead:
    ; Read the Disk Geometry
    mov ah, 8
    int 0x13
    ; Error Handling
    jc err
    ; continue
    inc dh
    mov [hct], dh
    and cl, 0x3F
    mov [spt], cl

    ; Convert LBA to CHS
    ; Store Sectors to read number (snm)
    mov [snm], ax
    ; Calculate temporary value (tmp) and sector
    mov ax, bx
    mov bx, [spt]
    div bx
    mov [tmp], al
    inc ah
    mov [sct], ah
    ; Calculate Head and Cylinder
    mov ax, 0
    mov dx, ax
    mov ax, [tmp]
    mov bx, [hct]
    div bx
    mov [hed], ax
    mov [cyl], dx

    ; Read the disk
    mov ah, 0x02
    mov al, [snm]
    mov ch, [cyl]
    mov cl, [sct]
    mov dh, [hed]
    mov bx, 0x7E00
    int 0x13
    ; Error handling
    jc err
    ret
    
main:
    pusha
    mov bx, 1
    mov ax, 1
    mov dl, [bdv]
    call lbaRead
    popa
    
    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov al, [0x7E00]
    int 0x10
    jmp $

err:
    mov ah, 0x0B
    mov bl, 0x4
    int 0x10
    jmp $

; Pad to 512 bytes and add 0x55AA cap
times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55, 0xaa



You did not initialize any segments. You should zero at least ds and es. Also do not put the data at the beginning in the execution path.

Alright, I added
mov ax, 0
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
to the start, did nothing though
Also completely filled the 512 byte sector with "H" and it didn't work

The jc err is in the wrong place as the and will clear CF. Also ax that is holding the sector to read is destroyed. es is destroyed as well since that is a return pointer. bx is destroyed too for good measure. lbaRead is missing a ret it will fall through into main so the printing code is never reached anyway.

16 bit div bx requires dx to be zero. It does not use ah and al. That is the 8 bit division. You are loading 16 bits from 8 bit variables. You do not set dl for the read.

I set dx to 0 and used the 16 bit registers, still nothing

There are a number of problems from registers being clobbered, the LBA to CHS equation being a bit incorrect among the other things Jester mentioned. I have done no cleanup of this code but changes like these should get you going: https://pastebin.com/077GdsKE

saint
/sānt/
noun
noun: saint; plural noun: saints
2.
informal
a very virtuous, kind, or patient person.

As it turns out the entire program was a complete and utter mess
thankfully Micheal Petch in the commands decided to just rewrite the entire thing
org 0x7C00
bits 16
 
mov ax, 0
mov es, ax
mov ds, ax
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0x7c00 ; Stack will grow down below the bootloader.
mov [bdv], dl
 
jmp main
 
 
; lbaRead
; Reads sectors using LBA
; bx: LBA Address
; ax: Number of sectors
; dl: Drive number
lbaRead:
    ; Save AX and BX
    mov [snm], ax
    push bx
 
    ; Read the Disk Geometry
    mov ah, 8
    mov di, 0
    int 0x13
    ; Error Handling
    jc err
    ; continue
    ; Int 0x13/ah=8 can set ES to non zero segment
    ; set ES back to 0
    mov ax, 0
    mov es, ax
 
    inc dh
    mov [hct], dh
    and cl, 0x3F
    mov [spt], cl
 
    ; Restore BX clobbered by previous int 13h
    pop bx
 
    ; Convert LBA to CHS
    ; Calculate temporary value (tmp) and sector
    mov dx, 0
    mov ax, bx
    mov bx, [spt]
    div bx
    inc dl
    mov [sct], dl
    ; Calculate Head and Cylinder
    mov dx, 0
    mov bx, [hct]
    div bx
    mov [hed], dl
    mov [cyl], ax
 
    ; Read the disk
    mov ah, 0x02
    mov al, [snm]
    mov ch, [cyl]
    mov cl, [sct]
    mov dh, [hed]
    mov dl, [bdv]
    mov bx, 0x7E00
    int 0x13
    ; Error handling
    jc err
    ret
 
main:
    pusha
    mov bx, 1
    mov ax, 1
    call lbaRead
    popa
 
    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov al, [0x7E00]
    int 0x10
    jmp $
 
err:
    mov ah, 0x0B
    mov bl, 0x4
    int 0x10
    jmp $
 
; Variables for CHS conversion
tmp: dw 0
sct: db 0
hed: db 0
cyl: dw 0
spt: dw 0
hct: dw 0
bdv: db 0
snm: dw 0
 
; Pad to 512 bytes and add 0x55AA cap
times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55, 0xaa

